# How to force Firefox session to save?

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to troubleshoot some bug in FF.

At some point after start (usually some days) when I try to open new tab, it does, bot in a wierd state: it does not takes focus and I can't click it. And one more side effect (altough it may be unrelated): it stops updating sessionstore file. If I try to restart browser, it crushes and on the next launch it opens about:sessionrestore page with outdated tabs.

So I want to find a way to force sessionstore update logic to execute on its own.